# ftp client: no rc file?

Tags: ftp

I know ftp client(classical ftp client of Unix, for example kftp or netkit-ftp binary) use the file `$HOME/.netrc`.
The syntax is really simple

```
machine ftpservername login myname password *******
```

But if I want for example to turn on or off the prompt(prompt off command) there is no `$HOME/.ftprc`?
Is possible to put configuration on `$HOME/.netrc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
First the only rc file of ftp client is `$HOME/.netrc` there is not ftprc at least under netkit-ftp.
For commands is really simple, we can define and use macros.

```
cat $HOME/.netrc
machine ftp.myserver.priv login anonymous password anonymous
macdef macrodef1
prompt off
```

The last line must be empty or return error.
To run the macro on ftp client we can use $

```
$macrodef1
```

To run the macro

```
echo "\$ macrodef1" | ftp -v ftp.myserver.priv
```

If we want a macro which run automatically we can define a configuration for specific machine, the macro is called "init" and is recognized for autorun by ftp client.

```
machine yourmachine.com login youruser password yourpass
macdef init
passive on
prompt off
```